# How to install Jcalender in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jcalendar

I'm looking for the procedure to install Jcalender in Eclipse Mars.
I have just started to use Swing and I am facing problem to take date input as it needed Jcalender to be installed on to Eclipse.

By looking at some tutorials I have added Jcalender into the Eclipse designer pallet:

[image]

But still I am getting following error for import statement:

[image]

A little help would be appreciated..Consider me a newbie.

Comment: Download the jar (http://toedter.com/jcalendar/) and add to classpath (search on how to add jar to classpath in eclipse)

Comment: thanks...i was not aware about anything about this...your solution sorted out the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download latest release from [toedter.com/jcalendar/](http://toedter.com/jcalendar/) and extract it.

Put `jcalendar-versionx.jar` in your class path. If you want to use the JGoodies Look and Feel, put also `jgoodies-looks-versionx.jar` in your class path.

Both are in the `lib` directory of the `JCalendar` distribution.

To add the jar/s (set classpath) **in Eclipse**:

Right click the

> Project > Build Path > Configure build path> Select Libraries tab >
>   Click Add External Libraries >

Select the jar's file you like to add